# How to forward domain requests to gae url

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, forward

I have different customers who own each their own hosted saas page on my gae app. for example:

- myapp.appspot.com/customer/123
- myapp.appspot.com/customer/456

each of the customers may want his domain name for example **theBigDomain.com** to "invisibilly" forward to **myapp.appspot.com/customer/123**

Please notice I want `theBigDomain.com/myservlet?id=theId#aBookmarkUrl` to be transmitted to the target url as `myapp.appspot.com/customer/123/myservlet?id=theId#aBookmarkUrl`

I searched for the google documentation and I can't find a way to do that.

Note: I don't want a redirect where the person who types `theBigDomain.com` finds he's not there anymore, and I don't want a frame to include my url in the `theBigDomain.com` since I want the user to be `able to click on the back button`.

In short, I want the domains to work as proxies, knowing that from what I know, proxies are not good for some content, for exampe, if my target link has a youtube video, this might not work. So I'm asking if there is a way to do a dns redirect for a url and not a domain???

Using subdomains is also limited: creating a subdomain for each customer will be a tedious work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using subdomains is also limited: creating a subdomain for each customer will be a tedious work...

How so? This could actually be a lot easier for you/your customers since your customers wouldn't have to deal with domain verification/DNS settings and all you would need to do is add one `*` (wildcard) host to your main domain pointing to `ghs.googlehosted.com` and adding `*.yourdomain.com` in your GAE apps's settings. In your app, in your framework of choice you would then see what subdomain the request came to and and handle it as the customer's unique id (instead of 123/456). [See here how you would determine the subdomain on python/webapp2](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html#common-request-attributes). If you're using a different combination of language/framework - there are alternatives functions as well.

If you still want the customers to use their own domains then it gets a little more complicated. First, they need to provide the full domain name to you, you then add it to your GAE app's settings. Next, you and your customers need to follow one of the verifications steps listed on this page: https://support.google.com/a/answer/60216?hl=en and once that is complete  you would need to ask your customers to create a CNAME record on their domains/subdomains pointing to `ghs.googlehosted.com`. Once the CNAME record is created, you would handle this just like the if these were subdomains on your own domain, i.e. in your framework determine what domain the request came to and handle it as a customer's unique ID to serve that customer's app.

Comment: Hi Mihail, thanks you just made me realize gae handles all subdomains by default as is mentioned here (I didn't know that, somehow I skipped it while reading :-) ) https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/domain

Sure I'm using the java server, and getting the request url is quite simple..

For the DNS settings it's ok, I can aquire the customers domain for them and do that settings. So thanks for making me realize that :-) . Everything was there, I just looked at it with a too hesitating eye :-D (it's not my speciality)

Best regards